# python: Бот не запускается по ошибке: loop attribute cannot be accessed in non-async contexts

Tags: python, discord.py

Я создаю бота на python со слэш командами и у меня выскакивает такая ошибка:

```
File "c:\Users\Александр\Desktop\бот mysticbars\bot.py", line 14, in <module>
    slash=SlashCommand(bot,sync_commands=True)
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Александр\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python311\site-packages\discord_slash\client.py", line 59, in __init__
    self._discord.loop.create_task(self.sync_all_commands(delete_from_unused_guilds))
    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Александр\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python311\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 140, in __getattr__
    raise AttributeError(msg)
AttributeError: loop attribute cannot be accessed in non-async contexts. Consider using either an asynchronous main function and passing it to asyncio.run or using asynchronous initialisation hooks such as Client.setup_hook
```

Я не знаю как решить проблему. У меня установлены библиотеки:(если будет нужно)

```
pip install discord
pip install requests
pip install discord-py-slash-command==1.1.2
```

Заранее спасибо за помощь

Так же я пытался сделать через этот код:

```py
async def main():
    await create_db_pool() # again, no need to run with AbstractLoopEvent if you can await
    await bot.start(TOKEN)

asyncio.run(main())
```

(возможно я не правильно понял как правильно им воспользоваться)

Comment: Недостаточно информации. Приложите код, где происходит ошибка

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Я обновил discord.py до последней версии и начал использовать: **@bot.tree.command**